# Warn the user loudly when the API response received

Tags: swift, background-process

The project scenario is when the api response play warn voice or something.

It must send request in background.For example user active warn system using button(on/off) and close the app. App check datas every 5 seconds in background. When `data == 1` play warn voice loudly. I looked notification systems and read some document for background. Which technologies should I use ? I've been using swift for 2 months. I'm trying to learn how to develop an app in iOS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you are looking to do is schedule local notifications along with background fetch. However, you can't reliably use background fetch to ping a server every 5 seconds, like you suggest. At best you can suggest to the operating system that the minimum time interval between background tasks is 5 seconds but it could be much longer. There's no way to reliable run a service in the background when an app is entirely closed.

More info:

User notifications: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

Background fetching: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions